# Facebook app development: select friend

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-friends

I am working on a Facebook app for sharing recipes and creating menus with friends: https://apps.facebook.com/336259823101185

I would like to create a way to select a friend and get their id (but not send any notifications or anything). Is there some sort of plugin that I can use? It seems like fb:friend-selector does what I'm looking for, but it's been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

A popular way of doing this is with this third party tool: https://github.com/mbrevoort/jquery-facebook-multi-friend-selector

There's no built-in method in the API to render such a dialog, you'd have to implement something yourself if that jquery example doesn't meet your use-case